# Avoid overlapping bounding boxes in Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, bounding-box, object-detection-api

I am using the Tensorflow Object Detection API to train my own numberplate detector. I used `ssd_mobilenet_v3_small_coco` as feature extractor. When I tested my model using the Object detection tutorial, I found that same object is detected multiple times. After some searching, I found that tensorflow uses `non_max_supression` but why the same object is detecting multiple times.

My configuration file is here

```py
# SSDLite with Mobilenet v3 large feature extractor.
# Trained on COCO14, initialized from scratch.
# 3.22M parameters, 1.02B FLOPs
# TPU-compatible.

model {
  ssd {
    inplace_batchnorm_update: true
    freeze_batchnorm: false
    num_classes: 1
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
        use_matmul_gather: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    encode_background_as_zeros: true
    anchor_generator {
      ssd_anchor_generator {
        num_layers: 6
        min_scale: 0.2
        max_scale: 0.95
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        aspect_ratios: 3.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.3333
      }
    }
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 320
        width: 320
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      convolutional_box_predictor {
        min_depth: 0
        max_depth: 0
        num_layers_before_predictor: 0
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 0.8
        kernel_size: 3
        use_depthwise: true
        box_code_size: 4
        apply_sigmoid_to_scores: false
        class_prediction_bias_init: -4.6
        conv_hyperparams {
          activation: RELU_6,
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.00004
            }
          }
          initializer {
            random_normal_initializer {
              stddev: 0.03
              mean: 0.0
            }
          }
          batch_norm {
            train: true,
            scale: true,
            center: true,
            decay: 0.97,
            epsilon: 0.001,
          }
        }
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'ssd_mobilenet_v3_large'
      min_depth: 16
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      use_depthwise: true
      conv_hyperparams {
        activation: RELU_6,
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 0.00004
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            stddev: 0.03
            mean: 0.0
          }
        }
        batch_norm {
          train: true,
          scale: true,
          center: true,
          decay: 0.97,
          epsilon: 0.001,
        }
      }
      override_base_feature_extractor_hyperparams: true
    }
    loss {
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid_focal {
          alpha: 0.75,
          gamma: 2.0
        }
      }
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
          delta: 1.0
        }
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    normalize_loc_loss_by_codesize: true
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 1e-8
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
        use_static_shapes: true
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 512
  sync_replicas: true
  startup_delay_steps: 0
  replicas_to_aggregate: 32
  num_steps: 400000
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2019_08_14/model.ckpt-1636"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    ssd_random_crop {
    }
  }
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: 0.4
          total_steps: 400000
          warmup_learning_rate: 0.13333
          warmup_steps: 2000
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  max_number_of_boxes: 100
  unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
}



train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "data/train.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "training/object-detection.pbtxt"
}

eval_config: {
  num_examples: 1850
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "data/test.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "training/object-detection.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
}
```

Output of my model is
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can refer it here
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/non_max_suppression

When you run your model on one image it spits out an
output dictionary ie output_dict

Set you threshold for prediction and we found out how many predictions are above our threshold ie length (Here i have used std 0.5)

```
length = len([i for i in output_dict['detection_scores'] if i>0.5]

boxes_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(output_dict['detection_boxes'][:length], np.float32)
scores_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(output_dict['detection_scores'][:length], np.float32)
selected_indices = tf.image.non_max_suppression(boxes=boxes_tensor, max_output_size=length, iou_threshold=<IOU YOU WANT TO SET>,scores=scores_tensor)
boxes = output_dict['detection_boxes'][tf.Session().run(selected_indices)]
scores = output_dict['detection_scores'][tf.Session().run(selected_indices)]
```

you will get boxes and their respective sores